# fixed menu on a certain part of the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, menu

how can i make a menu position to the top of my page while scrolling. well i can do that on my header. but not on a certain part of the page .let's say my other menu is position on a 980px height of the page . if i try to use position:fixed it will just hide the menu. even if i use z-index. here's the visual:

`+________________________+
|         HEADER MENU      <--- Fixed menu - stays at top even when scrolling.
+¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬+
|     CONTENT BEGINS     |
|          HERE          |
|                        |
|       OTHER MENU       | <---- This must stay on the top when i hit this menu 
|                        |         and stay while scrolling
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
+¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬¬+`

Comment: post your code please.

Comment: If you need css only you could try to use position: sticky but supports probably not too great/consistent. Otherwise you'll probably need to use javascript, test when the element reaches the top and change its position attribute.

Comment: @SLL can you show me how

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a codepen with an example of position: sticky and a basic jquery example. Remember there are some support issues but you're mostly okay at this point. But it is something to look into if you decide to use sticky.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WZGxrm?editors=1111 (remove comment syntax to show one option or the other)

```
#otherMenu {
  position: sticky;
  top: 50px;
}
```

Adds 50 to account for the height of the header:

```
var menu_position = $("#otherMenu").offset().top; 

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    if (($(document).scrollTop() + 50) >= menu_position){
$("#otherMenu").css({"position":"fixed", "top":"50px"});
    } else {   $("#otherMenu").css({"position":"static", "top":"auto"});
    }
});
```

Comment: this totally works. but problem is scrolling up! it doesn't go back to its original position

Comment: @jmv I updated the codepen for returning the menu when scrolling up. This is just a start depending on what you're looking to do. Looking around for "fixed header on scroll" or "jquery sticky header", etc. might help you further if needed.

Answer (score 0):

be sure that there's no overflow:hidden on the header container

Comment: there's no overflow:hidden. i guess what i'm looking for the postion:sticky. but it seems not to be working